# JavaScript not working in rails 5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use static javascript files without using the gems in my rails app. My `application.js` looks like this

```js
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require owl-carousel
//= require rails-ujs
```

And all of the Js file I have to add in javascript folder without using any gem using assets pipeline. [The final output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwcsL.png). But in my rails app [javascript is not working or not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3wpN.png). My `application.css.scss` looks like this:

```css
@import "bootstrap";
@import "style";
@import "owl-carousel";
```

And the code of `index.html.erb`

```html
<div class="app_screenshots_slides owl-carousel">
    <div class="single-shot">
        <%=image_tag("scr-img/1.png", alt: "")%>
    </div>
    <div class="single-shot">
        <%=image_tag("scr-img/2.png", alt: "")%>
    </div>
    <div class="single-shot">
        <%=image_tag("scr-img/3.png", alt: "")%>
    </div>
    <div class="single-shot">
        <%=image_tag("scr-img/4.png", alt: "")%>
    </div>
    <div class="single-shot">
        <%=image_tag("scr-img/1.png", alt: "")%>
    </div>
    <div class="single-shot">
        <%=image_tag("scr-img/3.png", alt: "")%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: javascript is not working on load. so check the console for errors. then set a breakpoint because you are not including the code about this problem

Comment: does your `application.html.erb` includes javascript_include_tag 'application'

Comment: yes i have include this

Comment: Here is the link of my Github repo and issue https://github.com/asdimalix/javascript-test/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your javascripts are actually loaded but the issue is your not initializing the owl carousel plugin. Just add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

at the boottom of your `home/index.html.erb` or in your relevant js file to make it work.

**Edit** - Fix for your current setup
The issue is your plugin is initialized before your actual html is loaded. The possible fixes are
**1.change**

```
    (function ($) {
    'use strict';


// :: 1.0 Owl Carousel Active Code
    if ($.fn.owlCarousel) {
        $(".welcome_slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 1500,
            nav: true,
            navText: ["<i class='pe-7s-angle-left'</i>", "<i class='pe-7s-angle-right'</i>"]
        });
        $(".app_screenshots_slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 800,
            margin: 30,
            center: true,
            dots: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                480: {
                    items: 3
                },
                992: {
                    items: 5
                }
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery)
```

;
in `assets/javascripts/owl-carousel.js` to

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($.fn.owlCarousel) {
        $(".welcome_slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 1500,
            nav: true,
            navText: ["<i class='pe-7s-angle-left'</i>", "<i class='pe-7s-angle-right'</i>"]
        });
        $(".app_screenshots_slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 800,
            margin: 30,
            center: true,
            dots: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                480: {
                    items: 3
                },
                992: {
                    items: 5
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

2. Move your `javascript_include_tag` in your `application.html.erb` to bottom of the page, just before `</body>` 
3. Move the owl carousel initialisation script from `owl-carousel.js` to your `home/index.html.erb`
Hope this will help.

Comment: I also initialize in the bottom of my owl carousel js file...like this

Comment: See here https://github.com/asdimalix/javascript-test/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/owl-carousel.js

Comment: You are welcome, It'll be nice if you could accept the answer if it was helpful.@devdap

Comment: just click the checkmark below the voting icons on left. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 0):

rails-ujs, introduced in Rails 5, is not for using jQuery - it was developed to get rid of jQuery dependency.

See my [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022899/4812102)