# Javascript not loading on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to deploy an application. My javascript is loading perfectly on development but it's not loading on the production. Even I am not getting any error in production. If someone needs more information please let me know.
I have already tried the below command

**heroku run rake assets:precompile --app my_app**

Also I have tried alert() function it is also not working on heroku.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                        animation: "fade",
                        slideshowSpeed: 4000,
                        animationSpeed: 600,
                        controlNav: false,
                        directionNav: true,
                        controlsContainer: ".flex-container" // the container that holds the flexslider
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.6)
      actionpack (= 5.0.6)
      nio4r (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.6)
      actionpack (= 5.0.6)
      actionview (= 5.0.6)
      activejob (= 5.0.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.6)
      actionview (= 5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
    activerecord (5.0.6)
      activemodel (= 5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arel (7.1.4)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.1.0)
    capybara (2.16.1)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    childprocess (0.8.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.18)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (0.9.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.10.3)
    multi_json (1.12.2)
    nio4r (2.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.1)
    puma (3.11.0)
    rack (2.0.3)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.6)
      actioncable (= 5.0.6)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.6)
      actionpack (= 5.0.6)
      actionview (= 5.0.6)
      activejob (= 5.0.6)
      activemodel (= 5.0.6)
      activerecord (= 5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.0.6)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.0.6)
      actionpack (= 5.0.6)
      activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.5.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.8.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
    tzinfo (1.2.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.0.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.5.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (2.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  capybara (~> 2.13)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (~> 0.18)
  puma (~> 3.7)
  rails (~> 5.0.5)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.4
```

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`. 
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "my_bagicha_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove **require_tree** and load your js in this fashion.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.flexslider-min
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 3):

## For Rails 6+ (or those using Webpacker)

If you've just deployed a newly minted rails app to Heroku, i.e. a Hobby tier or something like that, then you will need to ensure that you've added to the Node build pack:

#### (1) Ensure your heroku remote is set up:

- The following assumes heroku is the name of the git remote. You can check whether you have it set up by typing in:

`git remote -v`

...and you should see heroku listed there. If you can't see it, then you need to set up a git remote pointing to heroku.

#### (2) Add the NodeJS Buildpack

- This will clear the buildpacks - don't do it if you don't want to elminate your other build packs:

`heroku buildpacks:clear`

- Add the nodejs buildpack first (note: the order is important here: ruby must go AFTER nodejs)

`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs

heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby`

#### (3) Lastly, check that you are properly serving your assets:

In my case I am using the `style_sheet_pack_tag`

```
# application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag "application", media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

View on the console what is the error

If you use any jquery library then implement Gemfile with `jquery-rails` like below

```
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then install bundle

Then update `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
```

If your app using `turbolinks` then modify your code like below

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    slideshowSpeed: 4000,
    animationSpeed: 600,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true,
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container" // the container that holds the flexslider
  });
});
```

Hope to help

Comment: @ankur Check your browser console & check the error then put your error

Comment: @fool-  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: hi, @ankur: in your application.js maybe you should need to add "//= require turbolinks" too, do you have a stylesheet_link_tag in application.html.erb?

Comment: @Pietro Allievi -  I don't need to add turbolinks because I am not using any turbolinks functionality

Comment: ok @ankur this is the jquery not found an error you can try a different way https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+ReferenceError%3A+%24+is+not+defined&oq=Uncaught+ReferenceError%3A+%24+is+not+defined&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @fool - It is still not working on the production. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

`rails-ujs`, introduced in Rails 5, is not for using jQuery - it was developed to get rid of jQuery dependency.

So, if you still need jQuery, you need to have the following settings:

Gemfile:

`gem 'jquery-rails'`

application.js:

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

and remove the `//= require rails-ujs` if already present in `application.js`.

Comment: It is still not working on the production. I have updated my question

Comment: I could still see the `gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 5.1.0.beta1'` line in your Gemfile. It should be changed to `gem 'jquery-rails'`.

Comment: I have removed rails-ujs still not working. Also, I have updated my Gemfile and added Gemfile.lock. If you need more information let me know

Comment: The last idea that's coming to my mind is trying to clean the assets before precompiling them, also running the assets' tasks with a bundle exec

```
heroku run bundle exec rake assets:clean
heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: i tried cleaning and again precompiling assets still it didn't work for me

Comment: Sorry to be somewhat repetitive, but only yesterday have discovered that the old assets should be cleaned after the new are precompiled. So, you could try once again to first precompile, then clean.

Comment: I got an answer for the problem. Anyways thanks for helping

Comment: @aniketshivamtiwari- This guy has given the answer. I have marked his answer as correct

Comment: This was the right answer for me. Rails 5 has rails-ujs which is essentially jquery-ujs (without Jquery lol).. so with Rails 5; you will still need the jquery-rails gem if using Jquery anywhere. I added the gem, added //= require jquery as the first line in application.js and kept //= require rails-ujs, delete gemlock and bundle install, push to heroku.. All is well!